# AngularJS string with or in output

Tags: angularjs

The following will show an integer if set, and "-" if not set:

```
{{ movie.agemin || "-" }}
```

Now I would like to extend this to show the integer followed by " years" if set, or "-" if not set.

```
{{ movie.agemin + " years" || "-" }}
```

However, this now stops executing the or case and always adds " years" at the end, no matter the value.

How does this have to be changed to work correctly?

Comment: Do you understand WHY it has to be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{ movie.agemin && (movie.agemin + " years") || "-" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-show="movie.agemin">{{ movie.agemin + " years"}}</div>
<div ng-hide="movie.agemin">-</div>
```

instead of div, you can use ant html tag

Comment: It is preferable to keep the logic within the string, instead of adding extra DOM elements / markup.